# a tabu error: overfull \hbox in paragraph

Tags: tabu

I made a table using the tabu environment but the contents seem to exceed the cells. I don't know how to fix this. I also don't understand why -animate is broken into two lines. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell,interfaces-makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}to \textwidth{|X[c]|X[c]|X[l]||X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{causer}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Predicates} & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Construction Types}\\
\cline{4-8}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} & plama  & plamb  & plamchoa & plamchob & plamchoc\\
\hline
[+animate] & & \multirow{2}{*}{} & & & & &\\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-8}
[-animate] & & \multirow{2}{*}{} & & & & &\\
\hline
[+animate] & & \multirow{2}{*}{} & & & & &\\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-8}
[-animate] & & \multirow{2}{*}{} & & & & &\\
\hline
[+animate] & & \multirow{2}{*}{} & & & & &\\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-8}
[-animate] & & \multirow{2}{*}{} & & & & &\\
\hline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `-animate` is broken into two lines because it's being "hyphenated" (even though this isn't intended as a hyphen).  try putting dollar signs around the hyphen -- `$-$` -- to make it into a real ninus sign.  (i don't have a good answer for how to decrease the width of the dell contents other than using a smaller font.)